# Pourquoi le linguiste utilise le mot référent plutôt que référé?

Tags: linguistique

En linguistique, pourquoi l'usage semble préférer le mot référent, synonyme de référé, pour signifier l'objet réel ?

L'étymologie attribue le "e" de référent à l'anglais [referent](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rent).

Utiliser un dérivé de référant pour référer le référé, au sens propre indiquerait que c'est l'objet qui réfère ?

Comment explique le linguiste cette curieuse dérivation lexicale ?

Comment: Le référent, c'est spécifique à  la linguistique  saussurienne si mes souvenirs sont bons (référent, signifiant, signifié).  Le référent c'est l'objet dont on parle, le signifié/signifiant, ce que l'on voit/entend. Je ne pense pas que le mot soit employé de façon générale en linguistique.

Answer (score 3):

On va partir avec le premier terme à apparaître dans la langue française (XIVe siecle) :

Le verbe **référer**, directement issu du latin *referre*

Partant de là, on a le participe passé *référé* ainsi que le participe présent *référant* tous deux légitimement substantivables au besoin.

SAUF que... sauf que, comme le DHLF le fait observer, à l'exception d'une formule de droit, "*aucun des emplois transitifs de ce verbe ne s'est maintenu.*"

On ne connaît alors plus que l'usage pronominal (*se référer à*) (XVe)
Et c'est donc là que tu as raison : substantiver le participe présent d'un verbe pronominal, ce serait indiquer que c'est l'entité qui est "*SE référant à quelque chose d'autre*"

En parallèle de cela, l'anglais *to refer* poursuit sa vie de transitif indirect.
Vient ensuite (XIXe) Dumont traduisant un texte de Bentham dans lequel il trouve le substantif "*reference*" qu'il traduira en forgeant le mot français "référence". => (système de référence / ouvrage de référence...)

C'est de cette *référence* (effectivement directement issue de l'anglais donc) que circa 1955, vient le *référent*, le truc auquel on fait référence.

Voilà toute l'affaire. Tu l'avais d'ailleurs bien sentie venir sous l'angle du sens. Sous le point de vue grammatical, tout s'explique donc par la transitivité perdue par le référer français mais conservée par le to refer anglais.